# Stop pull to refresh after a delay

Tags: android

I would like to stop the pull to refresh after a delay so i did this but it doesn't work :

```
   final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the XML code i don't know if it's good  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:longClickable="true"





        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"


        android:text="" />


    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/semi_transparent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primaryColor"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/AccentColor"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:text="Vous n&apos;avez aucun coffy commencez par en ajouter un en cliquant sur le bouton +"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView3"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/semi_transparent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

i tried everything if someone find a solution it will be incredible

My Handler import :

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong in your code, but you can check this snip:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
            android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
}


@Override public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

I think your layout is wrong, The RelativeLayout should be inside SwipeRefreshLayout. Check this layout below, and note that if still does not work, you can bring xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to SwipeRefreshLayout properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:longClickable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/semi_transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="#ABCDEF"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/AccentColor"
            fab:fab_plusIconColor="@color/primaryTextColor"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:width="200dp"
            android:height="200dp"
            android:text="Vous n&apos;avez aucun coffy commencez par en ajouter un en cliquant sur le bouton +"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/semi_transparent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: yeah but it's in a fragment so it's a  bit different

Comment: It's still not working don't understand what 's wrong

Comment: can you post the xml layout.It may help.

Comment: it's still doing nothing maybe my import for the Handler is not good  seee my updated answer